# How can I create divs with conditional selects in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-template

Here is my html component:

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of barChartTypeSelect">
    {{chart.mainChart}}

    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedRepositoryName" (ngModelChange)="onRepositorySelected()">
        <option *ngFor=" let repository of barChartTypeSelect" [value]="repository.mainChart">
            {{repository.mainChart}}
        </option>
    </select>

</div>
```

In my typescript file, I defined the following:

```
private onRepositorySelected() {
        this.selectedRepository = this.barChartTypeSelect.find(repository => repository.mainChart === this.selectedRepositoryName);
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create dynamic divs based on a json file that I parsed. Each div contains a chart with a conditional selects to adjust it. By parsing the json file and being aware of each object, we can actually decide if we need to attach a selects or not (if the object only contains a key but without any value, then there is no selects).

In other words, the json object maps for each key on the first level to a chart. Every secondary level is a select option that redraws the chart on select, every third level is also a select option that only gets displayed if the second select is checked, and so on.

Here is the object parsed:

```
 {
    "consumerPriceIndex": [],
    "grossDomesticProductPercentage": [],
    "inflationRate": [],
    "newUnderCons": [
      "apartment",
      "building",
      "villa"
    ],
    "population": [
      "quarter",
      "year"
    ],
    "populationChange": [
      "quarter",
      "year"
    ],
    "transactionVolume": {
      "apartment": [
        "quarter",
        "year"
      ],
      "total": [
        "quarter",
        "year"
      ],
      "villa": [
        "quarter",
        "year"
      ]
    },
    "transactionVolumeOilIndex_total_quarter": []
  }
```

I can always hard code the values, but I want to achieve the mvc structure as closely as possible. Thank you.

Comment: This way every select control will have the same effect.

Comment: @micronyks so you do not recommend this approach?

Comment: Still your requirement is not clear to me. If you could tell us more what exactly you want?

Comment: @micronyks I have a json object that maps for each key on the first level to a chart. Every secondary level is a select option that redraws the chart on select, every third level is also a select option that only gets displayed if the second select is checked, and so on.. I'll update my question

Comment: Moreover you are using `{{char.mainChart}}` which(mainchart) I'm unable to find in json object.

Comment: @micronyks I mapped the json file to an interface, so mainChar in this case is transactionVolume, etc. the level 1 of the json file is the mainChart, every sub level is a select

Comment: Problem doesn't seem complex but i'm unable to understand it completely.    I guess plunker would help us (if you could create).

Comment: can't you just use `*ngIf` directive?